# corda's mainnet or our own network? when to use which?

Tags: corda

I have two doubt

> 1.In production, do we have to set up our own network or we have to use
>   Corda's existing mainnet?
>
> 2.If we use Corda's mainnet then do we still need to deploy Notary node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the road map looks like for `Corda Net`. But I think if you use the `corda net` then you definitely saving yourself the hazzel of setting up/maintaining a Network Map and a Doorman as they are part of the `Corda Net`.
With the`Corda Test Net`you definitely, get a `non-validating` Notary. The only problem here is everyone in would be using the same notary so if your use case allows it, you are good, also your node is visible to all since it's part of the global network map service.

Now, if the roadmap of `corda-net` has `sub-networks` and allows custom `CA` then it could be a good option for many enterprise solutions. (these are just my thoughts) Best would be to reach out to R3 for this.

If your use case has too much of regulation then go for your own  network else go on with the `corda test net`

Comment: Thanks, it really helped